# Keyboard input with accented characters: Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, java.util.scanner, non-ascii-characters

I'm having trouble correctly receiving keyboard input in Java when it has accented characters. For example, I'm trying to input something like "présenter" but it comes in as "pr?senter". I'm not sure how to fix this - I've been trying to use ISO-8859-1 encoding but I still can't get it. Here's part of my code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(
                        System.in, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
```

I also tried using UTF-8 but I have the same problem. Not sure what else to do! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to output the read char sequence to console? If so, then it's wrong. Console is not able to show accented characters as well as UTF-8 encoded characters. Just try to write your input to the file (as UTF-8) and check the file then.

The following code produces the correct result:

```
    String charset = "ISO-8859-1";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in, charset);

    System.out.print("Enter your text line: ");
    String line = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Your input: " + line);

    File file = new File("out.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    fos.write(line.getBytes(charset));
    fos.close();

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String readLine = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Your input (loaded from file): " + readLine);
    br.close();
    fr.close();
```

The output is:

```
    Enter your text line: présenter
    Your input: prÃ©senter
    Your input (loaded from file): présenter
```

The file content is correct. The wrong characters by "Your input" are because of local console settings, but the value in the file is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying to compare the user input to words in a file by using .equals. Basically the words in the file, which also contain accented characters, are first scanned into the program and then compared to what the user has input. The words from the file seem to be fine when brought in (they're in iso-8859-1) and they show up correctly in the terminal, but the user input isn't correctly compared to them. They don't equal each other if they're the same word. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: i'll try it tomorrow and write you my suggestions.

Comment: I tried that exact code and for some reason my output is still:
    Enter your text line: présenter
    Your input: pr?senter
    Your input (loaded from file): pr?senter 
Could I just have some setting wrong? Weird! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Check your system property for default character encoding. Print out all your props and check all of them. The try to use the same as defined in the example.